# Python: Passing unicode string to C++ module

Tags: c++, python, unicode, module

I'm working with an existing module at the moment that provides a C++ interface and does a few operations with strings.

I needed to use Unicode strings and the module unfortunately didn't have any support for a Unicode interface, so I wrote an extra function to add to the interface:

```
void SomeUnicodeFunction(const wchar_t* string)
```

However, when I attempt to use the following code in Python:

```
SomeModule.SomeUnicodeFunction(ctypes.c_wchar_p(unicode_string))
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    SomeModule.SomeUnicodeFunction(SomeModule, c_wchar_p)
did not match C++ signature:
    SomeUnicodeFunction(... {lvalue}, wchar_t const*)
```

(names have been changed).

I've tried changing wchar_t in the C++ module to Py_UNICODE with no success. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Boost.python doesn't automatically recognize the ctypes types, as far as I'm aware, but it should probably just work with built-in unicode strings. What happens if you try to call `SomeModule.SomeUnicodeFunction(unicode_string)`?

Comment: @Dough: the same error, but with "unicode" instead of "c_wchar_p" as the Python argument type.

Comment: @Matthew, w/ or w/o the `c_wchar_p` cast, it looks like it _should_ work except maybe for the `const` (which is nowhere mentioned in `ctypes`' docs) -- what happens if you omit the `const` in the C code?  (Note there's no direct C++ support in `ctypes`: the function must be `extern C` from a C++'s viewpoint, of course).

Comment: @Alex: even with a function declared extern "C" exposed by the module I still get the same error. It just outright does not want to take the Unicode string - conventional ASCII strings work fine though.

Comment: I see you've got a workaround, which is good. Can I ask which compiler/platform this is on? On some older compilers, where wchar_t is just a typedef, or is defined wrongly, this sort of thing fails.

Comment: @Doug: System gcc on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux you don't have to change your API, just do:

```
SomeModule.SomeFunction(str(s.encode('utf-8')))
```

On Windows all Unicode APIs are using UTF-16 LE (Little Endian) so you have to encode it this way:

```
SomeModule.SomeFunctionW(str(s.encode('utf-16-le')))
```

**Good to know**: wchar_t can have different sizes on different platforms: 8, 16 or 32 bits.

Comment: I'm using Linux, actually. I have updated my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Found a hack to work around the problem:

```
SomeModule.SomeUnicodeFunction(str(s.encode('utf-8')))
```

It seems to be working fine for my purposes so far.

Update: Actually, using UTF-8 means I avoid any need for SomeUnicodeFunction and can use the standard SomeFunction without specialising for unicode. Learn something new every day I guess :).